# SUM values based on non-distinct value of a column and distinct value of another at same time

Tags: sql

From table1, show the sum of sales amount based on conditions:

- The purchase amount must not be distinct
- (Year, Month) pair must be distinct

Must meet both conditions.

Example Table1:

[Database table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHqn1.png)

I tried using group by and subquery:

```
 SELECT sum(fin.tot1) FROM (SELECT SUM(sub.tot) as tot1
  FROM Table1 sp
    JOIN (SELECT id, year, month, sum(sales) as tot
           FROM Table1
           GROUP BY id,year,month
            HAVING COUNT(*)=1)sub ON sp.id=sub.id
    GROUP BY purchase
    HAVING COUNT(*)>1) fin
```

The above query didn't give the correct answer. I feel I'm missing something big here.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? You tagged three different DBMS (MySQL, SQL Server and PostgreSQL). I've removed all these tags. Please put in the one tag that applies.

Comment: Can be solved using any but for the tagging purpose can leave it at sql

Answer (score 0):

As I read this, this doesn't have anything to do with `GROUP BY`.

1. You want to show the sum of sales. This is one result row.
2. The purchase amount must not be distinct, i.e. you only take rows into the sum where exists another row with the same amount.
3. (Year, Month) pair must be distinct, i.e. you only take rows into the sum where not exists another row with the same (year, month).

The query:

```
select sum(sale)
from table1
where exists
(
  select null
  from table1 other
  where other.id <> table1.id
  and other.amount = table1.amount
)
and not exists
(
  select null
  from table1 other
  where other.id <> table1.id
  and other.year = table1.year
  and other.month = table1.month
);
```

### Update

In a below comment you explain that you don't want to apply the two conditions on your table equally, but want two phases instead. In a first stept you want to apply the first condition (non-distinct puchases) on the whole dataset. Then you want to apply the second condition (distinct year/month) on the remaining dataset only.

This gets most readable with a CTE (`WITH`clause) representing the first step:

```
with nondistinct as 
(
  select *
  from sale_purchase
  where exists
  (
    select null
    from sale_purchase other
    where other.id <> sale_purchase.id
    and other.purchase = sale_purchase.purchase
  )
)
select sum(sale)
from nondistinct
where not exists
(
  select null
  from nondistinct other
  where other.id <> nondistinct.id
  and other.year = nondistinct.year
  and other.month = nondistinct.month
);
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e830484474054701157ec969805be51a

Comment: Didn't get the correct answer with this either. 
Here is the  SQLfiddle link:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e86fa8/6   hope this helps and from what I understand the expected value is 913.  Thanks for helping!

Comment: Then it seems my interpretation of the task is wrong. But this is how I read it. How do *you* read it? Which of the rules have I misunderstood? How is that rule supposed to be understood? Seems to me this is rather a question about the English language than about SQL, because if I read the task and look at your data, I get 807 by manually calculating this, too :-)

Comment: Here is my interpretation, for the Purchase field you choose the ones having COUNT(Purchase)>1 so that it's non-distinct,
i.e. (Purchase: Sale- 100:106, 100:106, 350: 351, 350:350, 213:229, 213:230) and for the next condition (Year, Month) pair COUNT(*)=1  i.e. distinct values and from above Purchase: Sale table remove 213s as they have repeated (Year, Month) Now,  this sums up to 913.  By this logic, it should be 913 correct?

Comment: Okay, so there are not two conditions that you want applied on the table, but two steps, where only the first condition gets applied on the whole table, while the second condition gets applied only on the thus already filtered data set. I've added the solution to my answer.